# Filter only rows which were changed

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I the following code which if matches a given condition changes the price to mode price and if not - price is left the same.

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

digits_different <- function(mode, price){
  mode <- str_split(as.character(mode), "")[[1]]
  price <- str_split(as.character(price), "")[[1]]
  
  if(length(mode) < length(price)){
    mode <- c(mode, "0")
  }
  else if(length(price) < length(mode)) {
    price <- c(price, "0")
  }
  
  sum(mode != price)
}

df <- df %>% group_by(PPCODE) %>% filter(sum(PRICE != Mode(PRICE)) == 1) 

df <- df %>%  
   group_by(CODE) %>%
   summarise(MODE = Mode(PRICE)) %>% 
   right_join(dfn, by = "CODE") %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(
       PRICE = ifelse(digits_different(PRICE, MODE) == 1, MODE, PRICE)
      ) %>%
   select(-MODE) %>% 
   ungroup
```

Is it possible with R somehow to filter only the rows where prices **were changed**?

Comment: Add a flag to indicate which rows were changed and then filter on that.  Or svae the original values of `PRICE` in, say, `OLD_PRICE` and then filter on `PRICE != OLD_PRICE`.  But be aware of numerical precision issues if taking the latter approach.

Comment: @Limey maybe you can show me how to add this flag?

Comment: Just add it to the `mutate` call in which you modify `PRICE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement @Limey's suggestion:

```r
df <- df %>%  
   group_by(CODE) %>%
   summarise(MODE = Mode(PRICE)) %>% 
   right_join(dfn, by = "CODE") %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(
       FLAG = ifelse(digits_different(PRICE, MODE) == 1, 1, 0) # addition of flag to mutate
       PRICE = ifelse(digits_different(PRICE, MODE) == 1, MODE, PRICE)
      ) %>%
   select(-MODE) %>% 
   ungroup () %>%
   filter(FLAG == 1) # new filter condition
```

And here is another that keeps the columns separate, rather than overwriting the existing column

```r
df <- df %>%  
   group_by(CODE) %>%
   summarise(MODE = Mode(PRICE)) %>% 
   right_join(dfn, by = "CODE") %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(
       OLD_PRICE = PRICE # store the existing price so it is not overwritten
       NEW_PRICE = ifelse(digits_different(PRICE, MODE) == 1, MODE, PRICE)
      ) %>%
   select(-MODE) %>% 
   ungroup () %>%
   filter(OLD_PRICE != NEW_PRICE) # new filter condition
```